# Is it possible to add Python libs on Zeppelin from interpreter menu?

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to add the python libs through Zeppelin interpreter UI? I am installing it on the node through command line.

Comment: Hi, currently, You can use python.conda in Zeppelin to install lib in the para where you are working on. http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/interpreter/python.html#conda

Comment: Thanks, it should solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
%python.conda install [PACKAGE NAME]
```

For more info read the link
http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview2/interpreter/python.html#conda
Or you can use

```
%sh
pip3 install package_name
```

OR

```
 %sh
pip install package_name
```